# In GWT how to remove column header partially

Tags: gwt, gxt

In GWT on every column header there are four options - sort ascending, descending, columns, filters. I want to display only filter option and hide all other options. To disable completely I can do `column.setMenuDisabled(true)`. How do I disable partial header items?

Also I want to know how to mask grid when data is getting filtered in client side. `grid.setloadmask` does not help since filtering is done at client side.

Code snippet used to display column header:

```
ColumnConfig myColumn = new DefaultColumnConfig("name", "name", 92, true);
        myColumn.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
        myColumn.setRenderer(new GridCellRenderer<ModelData>() {

            @Override
            public Object render(ModelData model, String property, ColumnData config, int rowIndex, int colIndex,
                    ListStore<ModelData> store, Grid<ModelData> grid) {
                return ClientUtils.getTextToolTip(model.get("name").toString());
            }
        });
           myColumn.setMenuDisabled(false);
```

`setMenuDisabled` when set false displays all four options (sort ascending/ sort descending/columns/filters) in column header. I want only filter to be visible.
The commponent am using is GXT - `com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.grid.ColumnConfig`.
                                                                                                                     How do I get control over these menuitems of column?

Comment: Please include samples of what you've tried thus far.

Comment: There no such things like "filters" and "hide all" on stock GWT components. Please precise which 3rd-party widget library you're using (SmartGWT? GXT?)

Comment: The `setMenuDisabled` method can be found in gxt. What you could do is iterate the menu and disable the menuitems you don't want based on their text. It's a hack but it will work. These filters are generated automatically based on the type of the column (string, date, etc.) and I believe the library doesn't provide a way of disabling them partially. GXT is wonderful as long as you don't need anything outside the box. If you do, then be prepared for a lot of frustration.

Comment: How do I get the menuitems of column header?

Answer (score 0):

For each column config, set as follows:

```
columnConfig.setSortable(false);
columnConfig.setHideable(false);
```